# Normalize a matrix by rows containting zeros - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix which I want to normalize by rows (Euclidean space).
I tried to use normr, which is great except for the fact that it normalizes (0,0) to (1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)). In that case I'd like it to be (0,0).

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `any(M,2)` you get all rows which you want to normalize. Only run these rows through the function.

```
r=any(M,2);
M(r,:)=normr(M(r,;));
```